# How to manipulate heap size with custom malloc? (C++ LLVM)

Tags: c++, memory-management, malloc, llvm

I know it's possible to overwrite malloc, realloc, free, etc.

But I'm not seeing a way to manipulate the heap size as needed. How can I grow/shrink this as needed?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "heap" - it is not a standard term in C++.   With a fair few systems, it might refer to an area of memory managed by the operating system, which can be requested and made available to a program which can then allocate that memory for its own (temporary, as far as the host system is concerned) use.   The amount available is set and managed by the host platform (which is why programs, when dynamically allocating memory, request it from the system).   Overwriting `malloc()`, `free()`, etc are not the way to change that.

Answer (score 0):

The heap is that from which malloc returns memory.

Ancient implementations of malloc() would return memory that had been freed using free() if any was available, else request more memory from the unix kernel using [sbrk()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sbrk). More modern ones tend to use [mmap("/dev/zero")](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) or similar instead. Other operating systems generally are similar to one or both.

Limitations on heap size may be implemented either in malloc itself or in the OS mechanism that malloc uses.