# How to tell LLVM how big of heap to start with?

Tags: malloc, heap-memory

Trying to minimize startup time for a C++ program compiled with LLVM. For my specific application minimizing startup time is important.

One thought I've had was to tell the program to start with a large heap allocated so it doesn't have to grow and make system calls with subsequent malloc calls? Do I need to write my own malloc to do this?

Comment: You asked [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63445353) a month ago.

Answer (score 1):

If startup time is so important, then you make sure that your app is launched a long time before it is actually needed, and that all kinds of initialisations are done at that point. So when the app is really needed, you don't have startup cost, it's up and ready without delay.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work in my specific scenario, but I appreciate the thought, bet it'll work for others who stumble across this. Thank gnasher729.